# SQL Server 2019 cannot see Oracle 12.2.0 OraOLEDB12.dll in Providers list

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oraoledb

My SQL Server 2019 Enterprise is up and running on a Windows 2019 Core vm.  Connections to SQL Server databases are A-OK.

I have installed the OLEDB driver OraOLEDB12.dll via the oui.exe in the ODTwithODAC122011.zip.

I checked only the Oracle Provider for OLE DB in the Component Name list.
It created the appropriate TNSNAMES.ORA file from the info I provided.
The installer added the appropriate paths to the environment var PATH.
After restarting the Windows 2019 Core VM, and reconnecting SSMS v18.8 to the SQL Server I could not see the provider in the Server Objects, Linked Servers, Providers list.

So I ran regsvr32.exe and got back DllRegisterServer in OraOLEDB12.dll succeeded.  So I restarted the VM again, and reconnected to my SQL Server and still no joy.
What am I missing here?  I've search through lots of google links, on StackOverflow itself and am finding the same results, path issues, registry issues, 32/64 issues.  Our Ent SQL Server is x64, our SSMS locally is X64, the Oracle driver is x64.

[image: Environment Path]

[image: RegSvr32 success]

[image: Oracle Install Summary]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install more than one Oracle client? Oracle OLEDB driver can exist only once (i.e. once each for 32-bit and 64-bit).

Version of Oracle OLEDB driver must match exactly the Oracle client.

Maybe have a look at my [Oracle Connection Tester](https://github.com/Wernfried/connection-tester), this may give you an indication whether your Oracle OLEDB driver is properly installed.

Comment: Wernfried, Only 1 copy of the OLEDB driver on the server.  I solved the issue though, see next comment please.  Apologies for my mistake...G

Answer (score 0):

Gentlepersons,
My apologies, I did indeed install the 32 bit driver when I thought I was installing the 64 bit.
Have deinstalled (as Oracle calls it) the previous and am moving forward with the correct installation.
Again, my apologies for wasting time.
G

Comment: Just in case you need both the 32-bit and the 64-bit, follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100